# A function is differentiable with respect to the maximal atlas if and only if it is differentiable with respect to two arbitrary atlases

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $ X $ and $ Y $ be smooth manifolds. Let $ f\colon X\to Y $ be a function between the underlying sets.

Let's call $ f $  *differentiable* if for every $ x\in X $ and for every chart $ (V,\psi) $ of $ Y $ such that $ f(x)\in V $ there exists a chart $ (U,\phi) $ of $ X $ such that $ f(x)\in X $, $ f(U)\subset V $, and $ f_{\psi\phi} = \psi\circ f{\restriction}\circ\phi^{-1} $ is a $ \mathcal C^\infty $ mapping, where $ f{\restriction}\colon \phi(U)\to \psi(V) $ is the restriction of $ f $.

Equivalently, I can show that $ f $ is differentiable if and only if $ f $ is continuous, and for every pair of charts $ (U,\phi) $ of $ X $ and $ (V,\psi) $ of $ Y $ such that $ f(U)\subset V $, the function between euclidean spaces $ f_{\psi\phi} $ is a $ \mathcal C^\infty $ mapping.

Now, I want to prove the following.

> A function $ f\colon X\to Y $ is differentiable if and only if $ f $ is continuous and and there exists an atlas $ \mathscr A $ on $ X $ and an atlas $ \mathscr B $ on $ Y $ such that for every $ (U,\phi)\in \mathscr A $ and $ (V,\psi)\in \mathscr B $ such that $ f(U)\subset V $, the function $ f_{\psi\phi} $ is a $ \mathcal C^\infty $ mapping.

Assuming this (kinda weak) differentiability condition, I tried to prove that given two *arbitrary* charts $ (U,\phi) $ and $ (V,\psi) $ such that $ f(U)\subset V $ the function $  f_{\psi\phi} $ is a $ \mathcal C^\infty $ mapping by exhibiting for every $ b\in \phi(U) $ an open neighborhood $ b\in N\subset \phi(U) $ such that the restriction $ f_{\psi\phi}{\restriction_N} $ is infinitely differentiable. But I got stuck. Is what I am trying to prove even true?

Answer (score 1):

As written, you can run into problems in scenarios where there is a point $p \in X$ for which you cannot find any charts $(U, \phi) \in \mathscr A$ and $(V, \psi) \in \mathscr B$ such that $p \in U$ and $f(U) \subset V$.

Consider the following example. We take $X = Y = \mathbb R$. Our atlas $\mathscr A$ for $X$ consists of a single chart $(U, \phi)$, where $U = \mathbb R$ and $\phi$ is the canonical coordinate mapping. Our atlas $\mathscr B$ for $Y$ consists of a pair of charts, $(V_+, \psi_+)$ and $(V_-, \psi_-)$, where $V_+ = (-\epsilon, \infty)$ and $V_- = (-\infty, \epsilon)$ and $\psi_+$ and $\psi_-$ are the canonical coordinate mappings. Now let $f: X \to Y$ be the "identity map". As you can see, $f(U)$ is contained in neither $V_+$ nor $V_-$. So our "definition" of smoothness is completely vacuous, and fails to capture the notion of the map $f$ being smooth.

However, all is not lost. Let's modify the definition like so:

> **My definition:** $f : X \to Y$ is smooth if $f$ is continuous and there exist atlases $\mathscr A$ for $X$ and $\mathscr B$ for $Y$ compatible with the smooth structures on $X$ and $Y$, such that for every $(U, \phi) \in \mathscr A$ and for every $(V, \psi) \in \mathscr B$, the map $f_{\phi \psi} = (\psi \circ f \circ (\phi|_{U \cap f^{-1}(V)})^{-1}) : \phi(U \cap f^{-1}(V)) \to \psi(V)$ is smooth.

We've solved the problem! This new definition is no longer vacuous in the example I gave you. And we can indeed see that the map in my example is smooth according to this new definition.

---

Now let me demonstrate that my definition is equivalent to your original definition.

Before I begin, I'll reword your original definition slightly to emphasise something.

> **Your original definition:** $f : X \to Y$ is smooth if for every $p \in X$, there exist charts $(U, \phi)$ and $(V, \psi)$, taken from the *maximal atlases* for $X$ and $Y$, such that $p \in U$, $f(U) \subset V$ and $f_{\phi \psi} = (\psi \circ f \circ \phi^{-1}) : \phi(U) \to \psi(V)$ is smooth.

In rewording it like this, I'm making a point of emphasising the fact that the two charts are taken from the *maximal atlases*.

**My definition implies your original definition.** Suppose that $f$ is smooth according to my definition. Given a point $p \in X$, we can certainly find some chart $(U, \phi)$ in $\mathscr A$ that contains $p$, and we can certainly find some chart $(V, \psi)$ in $\mathscr B$ that contains $f(p)$. Now note that $(U \cap f^{-1}(V), \phi |_{U \cap f^{-1}(V)} )$, is also a chart on $X$! It's not a chart in $\mathscr A$, but it is nonetheless a chart in the *maximal atlas* for $X$. And clearly we have $p \in U \cap f^{-1}(V)$ and $f(U \cap f^{-1}(V)) \subset V$. Since $f$ is smooth according to my definition, $f_{\psi\phi} : \phi(U \cap f^{-1}(V)) \to \psi(V)$ is smooth. This shows that $f$ is smooth at $p$ according to your definition.

As an aside, let me spell out why $f$ must be assumed to be continuous in my definition. By assuming that $f$ is continuous, we are guaranteeing that $f^{-1}(V)$ is open, so $U \cap  f^{-1}(V)$ is open. It's necessary for $U \cap  f^{-1}(V)$ to be open in order for it to qualify as the domain of a chart.

**Your original definition implies my definition.** If $f$ is smooth by your definition, then for every $p \in X$, there exists a chart $(U_p, \phi_p)$ and a chart $(V_p, \psi_p)$ such that $p \in U_p$, $f(U_p) \subset V_p$ and $f_{\phi_p\psi_p} : \phi_p(U_p) \to \psi_p(V_p)$ is smooth.

Let's take $\mathscr A = \{ (U_p, \phi_p) : p \in X \}$ and let's take $\mathscr B $ to be the maximal atlas for $Y$.

To see that $f$ satisfies my definition, consider the charts $(U_p, \phi_p)$ and $(V, \psi)$, where $(V, \psi)$ is any chart in the maximal atlas for $Y$.

Note that $f_{\phi_p\psi} : \phi_p(U_p \cap f^{-1}(V)) \to \psi(V)$ is the composition of the map $f_{\phi_p\psi_p}|_{U_p \cap f^{-1}(V)} : \phi_p(U_p \cap f^{-1}(V)) \to \psi_p(V_p \cap V)$ and the map $(\psi \circ (\psi_p|_{V_p \cap V})^{-1} ) : \psi_p(V_p \cap V) \to \psi(V)$.

- The map $f_{\phi_p\psi_p}|_{U_p \cap f^{-1}(V)} : \phi_p(U_p \cap f^{-1}(V)) \to \psi_p(V_p \cap V)$ is a restriction of the map $f_{\phi_p\psi_p} : \phi_p(U_p) \to \psi_p(V_p)$, which is smooth by assumption.
- The map $(\psi \circ (\psi_p|_{V_p \cap V})^{-1} ) : \psi_p(V_p \cap V) \to \psi(V)$ is smooth *because it is the transition map between two charts*, and transition maps between charts are always smooth.

So $f_{\phi_p\psi}$, being the composition of two smooth maps, is smooth. This demonstrates that $f$ satisfies my definition of smoothness.

(Technically, we also have to verify that $f$ is continuous, but that follows immediately from the smoothness.)

---

Finally, let me give you a third definition of smoothness.

> **A third definition:** $f : X \to Y$ is smooth if $f$ is continuous and *for every* pair of atlases $\mathscr A$ and $\mathscr B$ for $X$ and $Y$ that are compatible with the smooth structures, we have that for every $(U, \phi) \in \mathscr A$ and for every $(V, \psi) \in \mathscr B$, the map $f_{\phi \psi} = (\psi \circ f \circ (\phi|_{U \cap f^{-1}(V)})^{-1}) : \phi(U \cap f^{-1}(V)) \to \psi(V)$ is smooth.

This third definition requires the condition to hold for *every* pair of atlases. It's stronger than my earlier definition, which only required the condition to hold for *one* pair of atlases. I think this third definition is what you were striving for towards the end of your post.

Fortunately, proving that this third definition is equivalent to my earlier definition is not too hard. The technique is one that we've already used: the trick of composing coordinate representations with (smooth) transition maps to switch between different charts. You'll have to apply this technique to the $U$'s as well as to the $V$'s. I hope you'll be able work through the details.

Comment: On rereading your question, I realise I misread your original definition. ("for all" $V$'s, but "there exists" a $U$). I don't haven't have time to edit what I've written. However, the ideas I've described still work and the arguments require a small amount of modification using the "composition with transition maps" technique.

Comment: To begin, this is a very clear and detailed answer. Thank you so much! Let me also say that the point of proving something like this ("there exists atlases such that...") is that in some (all?) cases you don't know explicitly how the maximal atlas on your manifold looks like. Instead, you have at hand only simpler (non maximal) atlases. For example, the manifold $ \mathbb R $ is given by "maximalizing" the atlas $ \{(\mathbb R,1_{\mathbb R})\} $. At this point you want an easy way (= that only depends on the data you know) to check that a map out or into your manifold is differentiable. 1/n

Comment: I completely agree! The power of these equivalences is that, if we can prove smoothness with respect to one pair of atlases, we've proven smoothness with respect to all pairs of atlases.